# Crashlytics not working with ionic framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, crashlytics

I am having an iOS ionic application in which I am trying to incorporate crashlytics, for that I have added [cordova crashlytics plugin](https://github.com/smistry-toushay/cordova-crashlytics-plugin).After that I launched the Fabric application and selected new application > projects xcode file > install crashlytics
after this step I added a run script build phase with the code in the fabric application and then build and run the application using xcode, but nothing is happening in the fabric application.

Attaching the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem trying to integrate Crashlytics into an Ionic app. The following worked for me.

1. Install the cordova-fabric-plugin:

   ionic plugin add cordova-fabric-plugin --variable FABRIC_API_KEY={api-key} --variable FABRIC_API_SECRET={api-secret} --save

This will automatically add a build phase script to the XCode Project.

2. Build and Run the project. The build phase script uploads a dSYM file which Crashlytics uses to process the crashes.

The first run after build is important as it identifies the build with the Crashlytics platform.